# how many file descriptors can select() manage in python socket?

Tags: python, sockets

When my multi-threaded program run, an error is thrown. I guess `select()` manages file descriptors too much, but not sure. Can someone explain this for me?

```
readables,writeables,exceptional = select.select(inputs,outputs, [])
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `select()` usually has a built-in limit on filedescriptors it can manage (1024 on most systems). Try `poll` or `epoll`, that might help.

Also note that `select()` uses an inefficient algorithm to manage filedescriptors lookup. This algorithm has O(n) computational complexity, while `epoll` has O(1).

Comment: I have read a document that said that select() manage a unlimited number of file descriptor in Unix, whether it's true when using select() in python to program in Unix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tested select(), there are exactly maximum 1024 file descriptors that can be managed by select()

Comment: Also worth noting that `poll(2)` suffers from the same issue as `select(2)` in terms of copyin overhead to kernel and in terms of iterating over fds. However, it is portable, where `epoll(2)` is not.